# Moving Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64) from my Internal HDD to an external SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have installed Ubuntu 22.03.3 LTS on my Windows 11 OS. My laptop is now running really slow, I bought an external SSD drive in order to move my Ubuntu to the external SSD and then uninstall Ubuntu on my Internal HDD.

My question is how can I do that? I have been researching to see and I can't find any tutorial on how I can do this.

Thank you for you help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.